# ComboBox com opções de CheckBox e Input Text

Tags: formulário, input, checkbox

Boa tarde pessoal, 
Gostaria de saber se é possível em um formulário criar uma combobox com opções para selecionar em checkBox e caixa de texto para preencher com um valor. (Conforme imagem) e que depois eu consiga enviar o item selecionado com o valor respectivo. Gostaria de algum exemplo se possível.

Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Antes de tudo dê uma olhada nesse post 
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485 e nesse também    https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Vai te ajudar muito nas suas perguntas

Comment: Tenho um exemplo com plugins, que aparenta um select com checkBoxes, veja exemplo http://kithomepage.com/sos/ComboBox-com-opcoes-de-CheckBox.html. Com checkboxes + inputs ainda não vi.

Answer (score 1):

Eu particularmente adoro o `Vue.js`.

Com ele é possível deixar a dinâmica de renderização de html em tempo real. Esse exemplo automatiza o processo de exibição do conteúdo.

Agora você só precisa receber esses dados de uma API sem ter que se preocupar em alterar o documento html toda vez que seu banco de dados ou API adicionar um novo produto.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#check',
  data: {
    checks: [
        {label: 'APPLE' , values: ['IPHONE' , 'IPAD']  , check:false},
        {label: 'LG' , values:  ['TVs' , 'SMARTPHONES']  , check:false}
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="check">
    <div v-for="check in checks" >
        <label >{{check.label}}</label>
        <input type="checkbox" v-on:click="check.check = check.check == false ? true : false">
        <select  v-if="check.check"> 
            <option v-for="value in check.values "  v-bind:value="value" >{{value}}
        </select>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela solução, é uma alternativa para o que eu preciso. Ajudou bastante! ;)

Answer (score 0):

É possível sim você pode fazer com que quando um checkbox é selecionado seja ativado o combobox. E quando o combobox altera seu valor o mesmo pode ser atribuído ao checkbox, da seguinte maneira:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
  checkbox[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    var input = this,
      select = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;

    input.value = select.value;
    select.disabled = !this.checked;
    select.onchange = function() {
      input.value = this.value;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>
      <span>IPhone</span>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </label>
    <select disabled>
      <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
      <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
      <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Diego, é bem próximo do que eu preciso, farei uns ajustes e posto o resultado! valeu mesmo ;)